# Run function/script in another script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I havd tried very hard to access and call a script's function from outside of the script.

----- this is inside a c# script attached to an animating sprite

```
    public class example : MonoBehaviour {
    void RunZebra() {
            Zebra other = GetComponent<Zebra>();
            other.RunIt();
        }
     }
```

------ Zebra script attached to a sprite anim

```
    public class Zebra : MonoBehaviour {
        public void RunIt() {
            // action starting animation

         }
     }
```

But it does not execute for some reason?

I need to access and set ScriptName's  variable so it's animation state is changed.

Any help and I'll be a happy man.

Comment: Please post actual code here. By the little info you gave it´s only possible to guess. For example it could be that the function you want to call is declared private, or you have a typo, or many other things.

Comment: Sorry. Have added more code.

Comment: If you correctly attached the `Zebra` and `example` component to the same gameobject and called `RunZebra` it should work without any issue. Are you confident the method is not called? Have you tried adding a `debug.log()` to make sure it wasn't being called?

Comment: This part looks legit = it should execute. To check that the method "Zebra.RunIt" is called, you can put debug output into it, e. g. by 'Debug.Log("Zebra.RunIt is called")' or similar. I guess the actual problem lies in the part "// action starting animation". So it would help if you supplied that code also.

Comment: (Augure was faster ;-) )

Comment: They are attached to two different objects. A man and a zebra (both have different Animator transition states, which are the ones I want to trigger from the scripts attached to them)

Comment: Have tried debugging - nothing in the debug console.

Comment: Ok, that could be one part of the explanation. `GetComponent<Zebra>();` only works if both scripts are attached on the same object.  Also see the answer below by Programmer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `RunZebra` script in your question is your complete script then your are missing something important.

*Your `RunZebra` function must be called from somewhere*. Either from the `Start()`, `Update()` function or from another script.

```
public class example : MonoBehaviour {

void Start()
{
    RunZebra();
}

void RunZebra() {
        Zebra other = GetComponent<Zebra>();
        other.RunIt();
    }
 }
```

If this does not solve your problem and `Debug.Log` is still not being displayed then you simply forgot to attach your `example` script to a GameObject. So, attach the `example` script to a GameObject that is *`enabled`*.

**EDIT**:

For the new null error, replace

`GetComponent<Zebra>();`

with

```
Zebra other = GameObject.Find("NameOfGameObjectZebraIsAttachedTo").GetComp‌​onent<Zebra>();
```

Comment: I have a RunZebra(); declaration in my example script. Perhaps it is not possible when Zebra and example are attached to different gameObjects? But how then do you keep track of each "character" on the scene? Ie. a man and a zebra?

Comment: I do not understand your current question. You main problem is that `RunZebra` does not execute for some reason. According to your comments, even `Debug.Log` does not work. This is a sign that the `RunZebra` function is not being called anywhere. Is the `Debug.Log` working now?

Comment: I have dragged 2 different sprites onto the same scene. Then I have added a script to each. I have tried the Debug.Log.  It now says: Object reference not set to an instance of an Object. Sorry. Am all new to Unity.

Comment: Then that is **one**  of the problems. The next step is to replace `Zebra other = GetComponent<Zebra>();` with `GameObject.Find("NameOfGameObjectZebraIsAttachedTo").GetComponent<Zebra>();`.

Comment: Where do I see its name? It's called Zebra - the sprite fof the zebra

Comment: Look the editor. The Hierarchy tab. The name of the GameObject the zebra script is attached to. Let me know if you are still confused...

Comment: Excellent. Thanks. I used gameObject.name in my debug. That worked!

Comment: IMO it is better for objects created at design time to link them statically to properties of other scripts instead of using `GameObject.Find` because of two reasons. First the `GameObject` to be found is linked by name into a foreign script which increases the coupling. If the scene object gets renamed unintentionally or willingly then all other scripts that bind the object by name will break. Second there is a performance hit (see the docs: <https://docs.unity3d.com/550/Documentation/ScriptReference/GameObject.Find.html>) which is acceptable in `Start` and `Awake` but surely not in `Update`.

Comment: @Jireugi I don't understand what you are trying to say here. Op wants to get `Zebra` instance from a GameObject dynamically instead of making it public and doing it from the Editor. That's why he used `GetComponent<Zebra>();`. Although that is failing because `Zebra` is attached to another GameObject instead of the current GameObject that script is attached to. So, we use `GameObject.Find` to find it then get `Zebra` component from it. There is **only** one `Zebra` in the scene, so there is absolutely no reason to use `GameObject.FindObjectsOfType` here.

Comment: Also, in my example, that line of code is being called from the `Start` function not in the `Update` function. Since OP did not provide where he is calling the `RunZebra` function from, I provided an example that called it from the `Start` function not in the `Update` function. It's OP's job to make `Zebra other` a global variable then do `GameObject.Find` once in the `Start` function then be able to use `other` variable anytime. There is nothing wrong with using the `GameObject.Find` function.

Answer (score 0):

I think I get the problem now. So you have some script named `example` attached to some GameObject `man` and one or more GameObjects that have the script `Zebra` attached to it. You want to execute the `Zebra.RunIt` method for each `Zebra` object by the `RunZebra` method of the `man` object.

To accomplish that you have to adapt the `example` script.

I suggest you use a public array of `Zebra` variables in the `example` script attached to the `man` GameObject. Then you can drag'n'drop each `Zebra` GameObject via the Unity3d editor UI into that array property field of the `man` object´s `example` script. (I named it `ZebraGameObject` below. You might have to set the `Size` property of the `ZebraGameObject` property first in the UI to the count of `Zebra` objects).

Then the Unity3d engine automatically gets references to each `Zebra` script for the `example` script from the previously set objects, so that the `RunIt` method can get called.

Nothing to change for the `Zebra` script assuming the code in `// action starting animation` is correct.

Here is the `example` script with the necessary adaptations.

```
using UnityEngine;

public class example : MonoBehaviour {

    public Zebra[] ZebraGameObject = null;

    void RunZebra() {
        if (ZebraGameObject != null){
            for (int i=0; i<ZebraGameObject.Length; i++){
                ZebraGameObject[i].RunIt();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

That method works great if the `Zebra` objects do not get spawned dynamically but are created at design time. If you need to handle dynamically created `Zebra` objects, then you might want to look into the [`GameObject.FindObjectsOfType` method](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.FindObjectsOfType.html) or maybe the [`GameObject.FindObjectsOfTypeAll` method](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Resources.FindObjectsOfTypeAll.html).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the HELP!!!

I did the following to set the Var of the Zebra (so it should animate):

```
    GameObject objectIs = GameObject.Find("Zebra");

            //print (objectIs.name);

            Animator zanimation;
            zanimation = objectIs.GetComponent<Animator> ();
            zanimation.SetBool("zebraLaugh", true);
```

This did the trick. Thanks "Programmer" - You really helped!

Cheers

Comment: Nice. That's how you get component from another GameObject. You only use `GetComponent<Animator> ();` without `obj.GetComponent` when you only want to get a component the GameObject **current** script is attached to. To get a component that is attached to another GameObject, you should find that GameObject first then get the component from it. Happy coding!